# Remove double quotes from an array in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, mongodb

```
var old_response = ["a,b,c","x,y,z","e,f,g"] 
new_response = ["a,b,c,x,y,z,e,f,g"]
```

Currently I am getting the `old_response` instead of that I need `new_response`

Comment: where is your `var` for `new_response`? and how are you getting the result?

Answer (score 2):

Simply join the elements using [`Array#join`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join) method and put into a new array.

```js
var old_response = ["a,b,c","x,y,z","e,f,g"] ;

var new_response = [old_response.join()];

console.log(new_response);
```

Answer (score 2):

```js
old_response = ["a,b,c","x,y,z","e,f,g"]
console.log([old_response.join()])
```

Answer (score 0):

You could cast your array to string:

```js
var old_response = ["a,b,c","x,y,z","e,f,g"]
var new_response = [old_response.toString()]  // or [old_response + '']

console.log(new_response)
```